# After installation of the Calendar Module all pages with calendar tags are blank

Tags: calendar, blank-screen

After installation of the Calendar EE extension, all the pages as blank, where I try to use Calendar tags, for example {exp:calendar:calendars}. Can you help me to resolve this situation?
Thanks